# Need comments on this Model architecture which uses versioning in Rails. Any suggestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, version-control, model, schema

Som Im trying to design an e-commerce system where vendor is able to add a product to be displayed on the site. The vendor can edit/update the product details, but they should not go "live" until and unless an admin reviews it.

I have several models that represent different products. Here is the design for one such product, but this same system will be applied to every product type.

Here is the diagram:[image]

Can I get some feedback on the pros and cons of this approach. 
Is there a better approach to solving this problem.
Is this scalable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is in the `is_current_products` and `awaiting_approvals` tables should be stored as a column and not a separate table.

Since current products will be queried a lot (each time a customer visits the site), it would be a big overhead to first fetch the `is_current_products` table then display the results from `products`. It will be an even bigger headache when you want to sort the `products` table.

How I would design this is have two tables: `products` and `product_versions`, where `products` represent all the approved information, and `product_versions` represent all the information regardless whether they are approved or historical.

Rough schema:

```
products
-id
-current_version_id
-#all the product information from newest approved version#

product_versions
-id
-product_id
-approved_by (can be null)
-approved_on (can be null)
-#all the product information from this version#
```

To display current product information, accessing the `products` table is sufficient.

To fetch the versions pending approval, just fetch all the ProductVersion where the approved_by or approved_on attribute is null.

To approve a version,
approved_by and approved_on will be changed on product_version, and information of product is changed to the current version, including current_version_id.

With this design, you can also revert to a older version while keeping all other versions in tact.

Hope this helps.